# Read node from XML file

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

A little confused with what im doing wrong here. My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customers xmlns="http://example.com/ns/" si="0" records="2">
  <customer id="123456789">
    <dob>2017-12-10T16:22:27.033Z</dob>
    <location>
      <number>444555666777</number>
    </location>
    <link rel="self" href="http://example.com" />
  </customer>
  <customer id="987654321">
    <dob>2017-12-11T17:00:00.033Z</dob>
    <location>
      <number>555666999888</number>
    </location>
    <link rel="self" href="http://example.com" />
  </customer>
  <link rel="self" href="http://example.com" />
</customers>
```

I'm trying to get the two records (customer) along with the data contained within them in this instance from a file (eventually i will change this to LoadXml as the XML targeted is from a URL but for testing i have copied into a file to work offline)

So my code

```
    Dim Xd As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    Xd.Load("C:\XMLFile1.xml")
    Dim Total As Integer = Xd.DocumentElement.Attributes("records").Value

    If Total > 0 Then
    Dim Customer = Xd.SelectSingleNode("/customers/customer")
```

Customer is always nothing? I have tried several variations including

```
Xd.SelectSingleNode("/customers")
Xd.SelectSingleNode("/customer")
```

I tried Xd.DocumentElement but i dont think this is correct either.

Where am i going wrong? Searched google and many examples are using the same as above?

**Edit**

I decided to look at Linq to XML and this is what i have

```
    Dim X As XElement = Xelement.Load("C:\XMLFile1.xml")
    Dim Total = Xelement.Attribute("records").Value
    Dim Customers As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = Xelement.Elements()

    ' Read the entire XML
    For Each c In Customers
        Console.WriteLine(c)
    Next
```

Looks good but i dont know if theres anything else i need to add or if theres a better way.

Comment: I strongly suspect the namespace is causing an issue here. While you *could* do it with XmlDocument, I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML instead (XDocument, XElement etc) as it makes the namespace handling much simpler.

Comment: ***God** has spoken...*

Comment: I have done what @JonSkeet advised and it looks like its resolved. Since theres no answer proposed and only direction i couldnt mark it an answer but i have edited my post to show what i did just in case someone crosses this thread in future. Happy for you to add an answer and i will accept

Comment: You could add your edit as an answer yourself and then mark it as the answer. You could even credit @JonSkeet in the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of loading the xml into objects

First define objects matching with xml format

```
[XmlRoot("customers", Namespace = "http://example.com/ns/")]
public class Customers
{
    [XmlAttribute("records")]
    public int Records { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("customer")]
    public Customer[] CustomerArray;
}

public class Customer
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("dob")]
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("location")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public Link Link { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [XmlElement("number")]
    public long Number { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    [XmlAttribute("rel")]
    public string Rel { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("href")]
    public string HRef { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize is as below

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer11 = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Customers));
Customers obj11 = (Customers)serializer11.Deserialize(XElement.Load(/* YOUR XML FILE PATH */).CreateReader());
```

Hope it helps.